# Abbreviating company names that are possessive

Tags: possessives

If I start a sentence with a company name that is possessive, should I use the apostrophe in the abbreviation after it?    The sentence reads, "DSK Lineal's (DSK or DSK's??) online geospatial..."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **individual** ownership is shown by making both (or all) parts possessive.

```
         DSK's or DSK Lineal's....both are appropriate.
```

However, **joint** ownership is shown by making the last word in the series possessive.

```
           Andrew and Jacob's factory (joint ownership)
```

Read more : [Apostrophes usage](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/apostrophes_show_possession.htm)